# Cell referencing a cell that has 'Alt+Enter' (or 'chr(10)' via VBA) ignores the line break

Tags: excel, vba

I think the image below explains everything. But why is it so and how to make "H1" look like "G1"?

(Office 2016)

[image]

Comment: Did you tick 'text wrapping'? It's under Start tab.

Comment: Just did now and it works. Thank you. So looks like the source cell gets it's 'Text Wrap' set automatically but not the 'descendant' cell. Maybe you would like to make an 'official' answer so i can tick it as the correct answer?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by 'How did you 'succeed' making that input in "H1" cell?'. "H1" is just a formula that refers to "G1" as shown in the image (=G1).

Comment: Ups.... I missed that part. I will delete my comment.

Comment: This sequence of conversations is messed up because a comment was deleted by @FaneDuru. It basically said "How did you get "H1" to look like it does in the image. I am in no way critical - just stating a fact to help readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, try to tick 'text wrapping'.

[image]

Or right click a cell > Allignment > Wrap Text.